# Nimbus Look And Feel Ignores Overrides for JTree

Tags: java, jtree, nimbus

I am using Java 7 and have implemented Nimbus Look And Feel on my desktop application. I am using a JTree and I am trying to control the colour of the text on the nodes by setting the UIDefaults. It works when the node is highlighted but when the node is not highlighted you cannot see the Text on the node.

I thought that setting

```
Tree.textForeground=\#ffffff
Tree.textBackground=\#4f4f4f
```

would do the trick , but it didn't. However if the node is highlighted then the following two settings work fine:

```
Tree.selectionBackground=\#71a3ff 
Tree.selectionForeground=\#ffffff
```

The only way I have managed to control the text's foreground is by changing the renderer as below.

```
tree = new JTree();
tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

UIDefaults defs = UIManager.getDefaults();
TreeRenderer renderer = new TreeRenderer();

renderer.setTextNonSelectionColor(defs.getColor("Tree.textForeground"));
tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

My questions are

1. Why the property Tree.textForeground not working
2. Is there another property that can be set for Non Selection Color ?

My Settings are as below

```
Tree.background=\#4f4f4f     
Tree.foreground=\#ffffff     
Tree.selectionBackground=\#71a3ff 
Tree.selectionForeground=\#ffffff
Tree.textForeground=\#ffffff    
Tree.textBackground=\#4f4f4f     
Tree.selectionBorderColor=\#71a3ff 
Tree.droplineColor=\#ff0000             
Tree[Enabled+Selected].background=\#71a3ff
Tree[Enabled+Selected].foreground=\#ffffff
```

Many Thanks in advance.